# Парсинг api карт python

Tags: python, api

Всем привет. Нужно спарсить все адреса и локации магазинов с сайта. Страница выглядит как https://www.kfc.ru/restaurants/ . Мне необходимо создать json с информацией о каждом магазине, его адресе, локации (61.0003213, 717.8241298), телефоне. Можно использовать selenium, но нужно обойтись без него. Смотрел вкладку network https://www.kfc.ru/restaurants/ , думаю что данные всех ресторанов прогружаются сразу, а не по клику, не знаю только где они все хранятся и как их достать, в html открывается div только по клику на ресторан на карте. Подскажите каким методом можно воспользоваться?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я смотрю вкладку Network и вижу:

```
https://api.kfc.com/api/store/v2/store.get_restaurants?showClosed=true
```

Answer (score 2):

В html ищете строчку

```
var restaurants
```

Где помимо всего прочего есть

```
"lat":"54.298660","lon":"26.8686
```

И т.д. Распарсить очень легко, даже не нужен селениум.